Mounting Android 7.0 userdata.img
I am trying to recover user data from a bricked Oukitel K3. The device had Android 7.0 and a MediaTek MT6750T processor.
SP Flash Tool enabled me to download the full contents of the EMMC. Then I extracted the userdata.img and decrypted it. (I found the decryption info and keys in metadata.img)
I'm now attempting to mount the decrypted image in order to access the files, but I am getting the following error:
$ mount -v -o ro,loop userdata.img /mnt/user_data/
mount: /mnt/user_data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

$ dmesg
[1] EXT4-fs (loop0): Unrecognized mount option "\\x1cb\\x1d\\xb6T\\xdcW\\xb35\\xe9<X\\xecm\\xd8\\x10" or missing value
[2] EXT4-fs (loop0): failed to parse options in superblock: \\x1cb\\x1d\\xb6T\\xdcW\\xb35\\xe9<X\\xecm\\xd8\\x10
[3] EXT4-fs (loop0): bad geometry: block count 1837508245 exceeds size of device (14178299 blocks)

The error seems to suggest that the filesystem is compressed in some way - i.e. sparse image. However, it doesn't have the magic header; output of simg_dump.py:
simg_dump.py: userdata.img: Magic should be 0xED26FF3A but is 0x97DCD0F0

Output of file command:
userdata.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files)

Output of fsstat command:
https://pastebin.com/raw/sXRS5WSc
Has anyone else ever encountered such issues?
It seems that I am very close to getting the data, but I just have no idea how to mount this file.
